# Split the file and further split specific index

Tags: python-3.x

I have a big configuration file which needs to be splitted per hierarchy based on specific syntax; completed. Among that on a specific string match I am pulling specific index and that index needs to be splitted further based on regex match"\s{8}exit" which is not working

---

```
import re

def config_readFile(filename):
    F=open(filename,"r")
    s=F.read()
    F.close()
    return re.split("#\-{50}",s)
return s

C = config_readFile('bng_config_input.txt')

print ('printing C:', C)
print (C.__len__())

vAAA_FIXED = []

for i in C:
    if "CRS-1-SUB1" in i:
        vAAA_FIXED.append(i)


# print (vAAA_FIXED)

print (vAAA_FIXED.__len__())
print(vAAA_FIXED)

vAAA_FIXED = vAAA_FIXED.split(" ")

print (vAAA_FIXED.__len__())
```

Need to get new list from the original list

Comment: Could you give us an example file with the expected and actual output?

Comment: Below config file is  a sample.

Comment: dear Palverez, i couldnt attach the file on this portal. and page doesnt allow to post more lines.  My requirement is to split the original raw text input with specific string and return specific index value as a list A. I would like to split further this list with another string to have multiple indexes without making that as a file and do split again.